# Joomla redirecting site to /en and I can't access the administrator panel

Tags: joomla-3.x

I'm setting up a site for development.

I'm not starting from scratch, I downloaded a live site, and now placed it in a dev environment to update some parts of it.

Thing is, when I enter the www.url.com/administration, it automatically adds a prefix to it (www.url.com/en/administration) which then results in a 404.

I tried turning of SEF and such, but so far I haven't figured out how to work around the issue.

Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The URL is wrong - it's not /administrat**ion** but url.com/administrator

Answer (score 0):

If you are not planning on making it a multilingual site, then make sure you disable these two plugins:

System - Language Filter
System - Language Code